# How to know which ApplicationCommands implements a .Net Framework WPF control (like Copy & Paste)?

Tags: c#, wpf, command, commandbinding

I was wondering how can I know which commands are implemented by the Controls delivered with the Framework. For example, how can I know if an Image implements the ApplicationCommands.Copy command or not? Or if a TextBox implements ApplicationCommands.Copy, ApplicationCommands.Cut, ApplicationCommands.Paste?

Extracted from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.copy.aspx):

> Some controls have built in CommandBindings for some commands. This
>   mechanism allows the semantics of a command to stay the same, while
>   the actual implementation is can change. A TextBox, for example,
>   handles the Paste command differently than a control designed to
>   support images, but the basic idea of what it means to paste something
>   stays the same. The command logic cannot be supplied by the command,
>   but rather must be supplied by the control or the application. Thanks
>   in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like the only way to know if a UserControl implements a standard command is to open it with a decompiler and look inside to see if it registers the command or not.

This is a big fail of Microsoft. This should be documented on the MSDN asap.